# making a list of functions using comprehension or for loop

Tags: python, lambda, list-comprehension

I need a list of functions, such as:

```
flist = []
flist.append(lambda x : 2*x )
flist.append(lambda x : 4*x )
flist.append(lambda x : 6*x )
print flist[0](1), flist[1](1), flist[2](1)
```

This works and the output is 2 4 6, as expected.
Now if I want to obtain this from a for loop:

```
flist = []
for n in range(3):
    flist.append(lambda x : 2*(n+1)*x)
print flist[0](1), flist[1](1), flist[2](1)
```

or using comprehension:

```
flist = []
flist = [lambda x : 2*(n+1)*x for n in range(3)]
print flist[0](1), flist[1](1), flist[2](1)
```

... I get 6 6 6 in both cases.
Of course I could use a function such as f(x,n) instead of a list. The reason  I need a list is for use in numpy.piecewise() or select() functions.
Any explanation/advice?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. You should add your programming language to the list of tags (I guess it's python).

Comment: Yes, I agree this was a duplicate and the previous answers solve my priblem. In the present notation, my favorite solution would be: